# How would I smooth out this jagged surface/edge on this mesh

Tags: modeling

Is there anyway to fix this, I shaded smooth in blender and it ended up coming out very ruff, even after merging by distance this time.
[image]

Comment: This could be because of strange geometry (view in wireframe mode), or because custom split normals data was created and then the mesh was changed, resulting in incorrect normals. If the mesh looks fine in wireframe mode, try clearing custom split normals data in Properties Editor -> Mesh tab

Comment: it can also be inverted normals or inner faces, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: you guys both helped solve this problem, after flipping the normals the results came out with very precise angles.

Comment: I solved it thanks to the help of everyone telling me to flip normals. @moonboots and TheLabCat also I wanted to give you guys a check by your comment for helping me but it doesn't give me the option, or maybe the problem is client side meaning they didn't submit it as an answer.